# Loop through twig array in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I'm having trouble looping through what I'm hoping is a simple data array in an html.twig file in Drupal 8. When I add the below block to a page, Drupal encounters an "unexpected error". And for now it's okay that this is static to the page.

Note: I'm less than a week into Drupal and twig and my PHP is 10 years rusty.

```
{%

set top_customers = {
   { name: "Altera G", logo: "logo-alterg.png", }
   { name: "Hollywood Was Museum", logo: "logo-hollywoodwaxmuseum.png", }
   { name: "iroaHealth", logo: "logo-iorahealth.png", }
   { name: "Lionel", logo: "logo-lionel.png", }
   { name: "Mashable", logo: "logo-mashable.png", }
   { name: "People Fluent", logo: "logo-peoplefluent.png", }
   { name: "Shop Kick", logo: "logo-shopkick.png", }
   { name: "Wistia", logo: "logo-wistia.png", }
 }

 %}   

 {{ dump(top_customers) }}

<section class="row cta-section row-padding-130">
    <div class="row-inner site-width">
        <div class="brick-10 center-brick">
            <h3>These brands are changing the way they think about AP by using MineralTree</h3>
        </div>  
        <div class="brick-12 center-brick">
            <ul class="logo-list margin-top-78 clearfix">
                {% for customer in top_customers %}
                <li>
                    <img class="customer-logo img-fluid" src="{{ directory }}/images/customer-logos/{{ customer.logo }}" alt="{{ customer.name }}" />
                </li>   
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="brick-6 center-brick">  
            <div class="margin-top-78"> 
                <a href="/about-us/our-customers.html" class="solid-cta-btn button-large">view all our customers</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you have anymore with that error? It is hard to start when we don't know where to look.

Comment: Recent log messages shows: "Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in "themes/custom/mineraltree/templates/region--banner5.html.twig" at line 4. in Twig_ExpressionParser->parseHashExpression() (line 281 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mineraltree/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `top_customers` as array as follow:

```
{%

set top_customers = [
   { name: "Altera G", logo: "logo-alterg.png" },
   { name: "Hollywood Was Museum", logo: "logo-hollywoodwaxmuseum.png", },
   { name: "iroaHealth", logo: "logo-iorahealth.png", },
   { name: "Lionel", logo: "logo-lionel.png", },
   { name: "Mashable", logo: "logo-mashable.png", },
   { name: "People Fluent", logo: "logo-peoplefluent.png", },
   { name: "Shop Kick", logo: "logo-shopkick.png", },
   { name: "Wistia", logo: "logo-wistia.png", },
 ]

 %}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/eigzl9) a working example

Comment: Thanks @Mateo! I'm converting from Middleman to Drupal and have data loops all over the place... This is a huge help for me.